# Simulate deriving from a value type

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, set, alias

I am building a calculator, and I would like to have a type called `ButtonDigit`, which may contain chars `0` to `9`, and I would like to call it `ButtonDigit'. Ideally it would be derived from`char`, but that isn't allowed, and I don't want an object like:

```
public class ButtonChar
{
    public char Value { get; set; }
}
```

I find that rather clumsy having to always instantiate a `ButtonChar` object and access the `Value` property when I want the character stored. What would be ideal is a type of alias for the char set `0-9`, but we don't get that. Am I stuck with a `ButtonChar` object, or a plain `char` and always checking it's in the range?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @TGH, sorry, I've added the C# tag that I forgot the first time.

Comment: What is the difference between a ButtonChar and a char?

Comment: @SoMoS, I quite purposefully explain in the first sentence of my question that a `ButtonChar` may only have the values `0` to `9`. It is general knowledge that `char` may contain any 16 bit Unicode character. Therefore, the difference is 65525 allowable values, which is quite a difference if you ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char is a struct, so you can't inherit it. I would say the custom ButtonChar class is a decent approach though.

Another approach is to just create a bunch of char constants

```
public static class MyConstants
{ 
  public static char Zero{get{return '0';}}
  ....
}
```

The range comparison will be easy since it's a sequential range 0-9

Comment: I actually ended up using constants even before reading this, but it is tiny and neat, although samy's suggestion of using generics is technically juicier.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [generic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) to handle different types

```
public class Button<T>
{
    public T {get;set;}
}
```

You can add a generic validation system on the setter - for example by keeping a list of Func that would be applied to any input, eg:

```
var validations = new List<Func<T, bool>>();
if (validations.Any(validation => !validation(tValue))) {
    throw new InvalidValueException(tValue);
}

// in the char example
validations.Add(myChar => myChar <= '9' && myChar >= '0');
```